# Send Voice message in android application?

Tags: android

I need your help please. I am developing my FYP on Social application in android. I have to send voice message frome one user to another over wifi and store it in database. Is there any suggestions of tutorials to send voice message through wifi and that message stored on server database? please if anybody have some tutorials or guidelines please suggest me. I'll be thankful to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there is an open source library called "Libstreaming" used for transmitting voice / video over the network via WIFI.

I leave the link for you to review
https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming

There are also examples
https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming-examples

I used the library RTSP Stream audio over the network, I hope you find it useful.

Comment: could you vote for my answer please?